# Reading correctly from a file

Tags: c, file-io

During the course of my program,

1. I pass the output of an execv() to a file, for logging, (using the outCopy() function)
2. and then print it back on screen to simulate stdout output. (using the printFile() function)

The 2 functions are:

```
void printFile(char *fileName)
{
    char *fileContent=(char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));                 /* sufficiently large buffer */
    if((filePtr=fopen(fileName,"r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n",fileName,strerror(errno));
        if( (strcmp(fileName,"/tmp/command.log")==0) || (strcmp(fileName,"/tmp/output.log")==0) ){exitStatus=255;}
    }
    else
    {
        while(fscanf(filePtr,"%s",fileContent)!=EOF)   
        {
            printf("%s",fileContent);
            printf("%c",fgetc(filePtr));
        }
        fclose(filePtr);
    }
}

void outCopy(char *fileName)   
{
    char *fileContent=(char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));                 /* sufficiently large buffer */
    if( (filePtr=fopen(fileName,"r"))==NULL || (filePtr2=fopen("/tmp/output.log","a"))==NULL )
    {
        printf("Error opening files: %s\n",strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        while(fscanf(filePtr,"%s",fileContent)!=EOF)   
        {
            fprintf(filePtr2,"%s",fileContent);
            fprintf(filePtr2,"%c",fgetc(filePtr));
        }
        fclose(filePtr);
        fclose(filePtr2);
    }
}
```

However, my neat little scheme gets disturbed for the output of the `ls` command:

Expected output:

```
a.c c.c e.c
b.c d.c
```

Current output:

```
a.c
b.c
c.c
d.c
e.c
```

How can I change either or both of my functions to get the proper output?

(Please don't suggest using pipes or tees, or I will have to change a major portion of my exec() calling child)

**Edit:** Please note that both the `outCopy()`  & the `printFile()` are run by the **parent**. Output has  already been `dup2()` ed to the required temp file by the **child**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of `ls` (including the GNU version used in Linux) detect whether they are being run with a terminal or with a pipe as standard output, and change their formatting. If you want exactly the same output, you'll need to create a pseudo-TTY (pty) using the [posix_openpt](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/posix_openpt.html) call and friends. Or you can use the [`script`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) utility, which takes care of this for you.

Another option is to use the `-C` option to `ls` to force columnar layout; however, this may not be exactly the same, as `ls` won't know the width of your terminal, and may assume the wrong width. Additionally, other features such as colored output may be missing.

Comment: is colored output a feature of ls or of the shell? I saw a variable in env which had the name "LS_COLORS"

Comment: **though I found that because my program SEGFAULTed on env command, as the line had 1279 characters :)

Comment: Colored output is a feature of `ls`, not the shell. However, the shell initialization scripts may set up `LS_COLORS` and the aliases to enable colors - this is not a feature of your shell, but rather of your linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

When stdout is not a tty, `ls` changes behavior from user-friendly columns to script-friendly lists. The flag `ls -C` forces columnar output regardless of the type of device stdout is attached to.

Comment: `ls -C` doesn't work quite the same way - it assumes a 80-column screen width, rather than using the actual screen width.

Comment: by columnar output, you mean the expected output?

Comment: Yes, I mean the expected output, and you can use the `--width=n` option if you want control over the output line width.

Comment: can the output width be grabbed from some environment variable or something equivalent?